# How Can You Find What the Model Names Are When You Generate a Model in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When you create model by `rails generate model`, I don't think any name should be safe, but I don't know what the names are safe.

Do you know how to check the name is safe to use as a Model name of `ActiveRecord`?

e.g.) The following shows a valid execution, but the name of `ApplicationController` as a Model shouldn't be happy, but in this case apparently the class name conflict, but `Rails::Generators::Base` can't detect the conflict.

```
$ rails g model ApplicationController
Running via Spring preloader in process 22976
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20170720064556_create_application_controllers.rb
      create    app/models/application_controller.rb
      invoke    test_unit
      create      test/models/application_controller_test.rb
      create      test/fixtures/application_controllers.yml
```

Comment: what\] do you mean by safe we can make any model name like

Comment: like rails generate model User

Comment: _I don't think any name should be safe_ -- do you mean naming conflicts?

Comment: Yes, the concern I meant was naming conflicts.

Comment: Rails throws an error if a model already exists. You can see what models are already created by looking at the `models` folder, and act accordingly.

Comment: When there are naming conflicts, rails informs you before creating the model and migration files. It asks you whether to override the existing files. Only when you press enter, it proceeds.

Comment: Oh, okay. I tried like *rails g model ActiveRecord*, rails let me alert that *The name 'ActiveRecord' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.*, so don't I have to be so worried before creating a model?

Answer (score 0):

> The model is named using the class naming convention of unbroken MixedCase and is always the singular of the table name, e.g. table name might be orders, the model name would be Order. Rails will then look for the class definition in a file called order.rb in the /app/models directory. If the model class name has multiple capitalized words, the table name is assumed to have underscores between these words.